# Error getting in button click event in android

Tags: java, android

I'm generating a click event in android and i used wrote the code in this way

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText inputEmail,inputPassword;
    protected String enteredEmail;
    String enteredPassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
       // inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
       // inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }});}
```

but getting the below error

```
TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please
> switch to using that class instead. 03-11 01:41:52.214
> 21936-21936/com.example.smartlayer.myhive_app I/TextInputLayout:
> EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that
> class instead. 03-11 01:41:52.294
> 21936-21936/com.example.smartlayer.myhive_app D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM 03-11 01:41:52.294
> 21936-21936/com.example.smartlayer.myhive_app W/dalvikvm: threadid=1:
> thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ae3ba8) 03-11
> 01:41:52.334 21936-21936/com.example.smartlayer.myhive_app
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                               
> Process: com.example.smartlayer.myhive_app, PID: 21936                
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

How i solve this error ?

Comment: please initialize the button like this                                                               btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to initialize `Button`

```
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set_Button_Id);
```

**Like**

```
 btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set_Button_Id);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }});}
```